# how to get the total size of all the nested array inside a Array of documents in mongodb without using unwind

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to get the total count of phone numbers in a single document, which contains a contacts field array with objects, the single element within this array as another nested array which contains multiple phone details. So, i need the count total phone details in the document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7a9c0097c3d53d1504d768"),
    "contacts" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "scentist",
            "phonedetails" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7a9c6097c3d53d1504d76a"),
                    "phoneno" : "1234567890",
                    "phonetype" : "mobile"
                }
            ],
            "email" : "boron@gmail.com"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "beryilliumMan",
            "phonedetails" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7a9ce097c3d53d1504d7ef"),
                    "phoneno" : "12345678909",
                    "phonetype" : "home",
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7a9c6097c3d53d1504d76a"),
                    "phoneno" : "1234567890",
                    "phonetype" : "mobile"
                }
            ],
            "email" : "beryillium@gmail.com",
        }
    ],
    "creation_dt" : ISODate("2019-09-12T19:26:56.817Z"),     
    "__v" : 0,
}
```

Query to get the total number of phonedetails in the document.
In the above example total phonedetails is 3

Comment: Mind supplying some sample data (it can be fake data - more concerned with the structure) - so we have a better idea of what your "schema" looks like?

Comment: Why "without using unwind"?

Comment: I don't have full knowledge on the queries. I think using $unwind and $group i can't get all the fields of the document along with that calculated new field

Answer (score 0):

I cannot figure out why you do not want to use `$unwind`, but it definitely make things easy here:

```
db.getCollection('TestSO').aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "_id": ObjectId("5d7a9c0097c3d53d1504d768")
        },
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$contacts"
    },
    {
        $group: { 
            "_id": null, 
            "count_items": { 
                $sum: {
                    $size: "$contacts.phonedetails"
                }
            } 
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "_id": 0,
            "count_items": 1
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: Thankyou! @Marco Luzzara for the solution. But  is there any other way like using with $filter and summing up the fields of phonedetails of the document.

Comment: *Selects a subset of an array to return based on the specified condition. Returns an array with only those elements that match the condition.* This is what doc says about `$filter`, I do not think it can be of any help in this case.